# How to set minDate of a ngbDatepicker programatically using today date

Tags: angular, datepicker

I am trying to use the Today date as the minDate of a ngbDatepicker

In the component logi I have the following

```
export class ShareLinkFormComponent implements OnInit {

  minPickerDate = "{year: " + new Date().getFullYear() + ", month: 6, day: 27}" ;
```

I have used the actual month and day until I get the basic concept working

And int the template/html side I have this

```
<input
  class="d-none"
  name="expDate"
  ngbDatepicker
  #d="ngbDatepicker"
  [minDate]="minPickerDate" 
  [(ngModel)]="expirationDate"
  (ngModelChange)="onFromDateSelect($event)"
  style="top: 100px;"
/>
```

But this is not working since the date picker is showing dates in the past enabled

What am I doing wrong and can it be implemented correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make it work you need to use an object using the structure/reference of the  **[NgbDateStruct](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbDateStruct)** interface and they are all of type number not string:

```
minPickerDate = {
    year: new Date().getFullYear(),
    month: new Date().getMonth() + 1,
    day: new Date().getDate()
};
```

- `getMonth()` returns from 0-11 so you need to add a one (1) to make it work
- `getDate()` returns the number of the month (getDay returns the day of the week)